# In Html Click On list (li) item not working with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to Html,jQuery coding.I want to change background color of item selected(clicked) of an li.
I have my code below :

```
 #In HTML#

<div id="major" class="major-funds form-group"><strong>Major funds (above 1.0% market share)</strong>
<ul>
<li style="list-style: none; display:inline;padding-left:5px;" class="text-primary" ng-click="GetProducts(x.code)" ng-repeat="x in Major">{{x.code}}</li>
</ul>
</div>

# In controller#

$('#major li').click(function () {
   $('li').removeClass('text-primary.selected');
   $(this).addClass('text-primary.selected');
});
```

What am I doing wrong ? When I click on li item, It doesn't call that function.
 IF I use this dynamic list it doesn't hit that function but if I use static list it does hit that function.How should I implement click function for dynamic list?

Comment: you don't use dot in `removeClass` or `addClass`.

Comment: Please provide your CSS. But my guess is you should use only `selected` instead of `text-primary.selected` in the JS part.

Comment: It's a name of class in CSS and my problem is when I click on item It's not go into that function.@Mike

Comment: Maybe you're not waiting until the dom is ready before you execute your JS? See my updated answer with wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: I have tried it ,but still it doesn't hit that function.I have written that code in angularjs controller.Is that okay ?@mpf82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event is triggered (check with console.log function) but the action you execute are not defined properly.

```
$('li').removeClass('text-primary.selected');
$(this).addClass('text-primary.selected');
```

should be

```
$('li').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

If your list is dynamically generated (not in the DOM on page load), the problem may come from the click function. In this case, just use :

```
$(document).on('click', '#major li', function () {
   $('li').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

where you can replace document by the container of your list. Per example :

```
$('#major').on('click', 'li', function () {
   $('li').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Here is a JSfiddle with working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ztvdnh86/2/

Answer (score 3):

> When I click on li item, It doesn't call that function.

Are you sure JQuery is loaded properly?
Are you sure, you're not setting another click event for your list items?
Is your CSS defined correctly?

Anyway, this works for me:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#major li').click(function () {
       $('li').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
       console.log("HERE");
    });
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="major" class="major-funds form-group"><strong>Major funds (above 1.0% market share)</strong>
<ul>
<li>XXXXX</li>
<li>YYYY</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# In controller#

$('#major li').click(function () {
   $('li.selected').removeClass('text-primary selected');
   $(this).addClass('text-primary selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you've written `'text-primary.selected'` tries to select the element with the tag-name `text-primary` with the class `.selected`

what you want to do is to remove the `selected` class from all the lis with the class `text-primary` and then add the class `selected` to the clicked (selected) element:

```
$('#major li').click(function () {
   $('li.text-primary.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```